# Executing multiple background find requests on parse.com results in an error with Code: 154

Tags: multithreading, swift, parse-platform, uisearchdisplaycontroller

```
Error: The number of regex find operations in progress has reached its limit. (Code: 154, Version: 1.2.21)
```

This error occurs when I execute findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock too many times on concurrent threads. I'd like to know if there is any solution to this error or even documentation regarding its official cause. I cannot see any explanation for this error on Parse.com.

The source of the requests in a search bar. With each character typed in the search bar, I make these queries and populate a table based on the results.

```
var queryOuter = PFQuery(className: "OuterList")
    queryOuter.whereKey("name", containsString: searchTerm)
    queryOuter.limit = 10
    queryOuter.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            var tempArr = [PFObject]()
            var tempArrOuterListSearchResults = [PFObject]()
            for object in objects {
                tempArrOuterListSearchResults.append(object as PFObject)
            }
            self.searchResultsForOuterList.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            self.searchResultsForOuterList = tempArrOuterListSearchResults
        }
        else {
            println ("encountered error...probably regex")
        }
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.reloadData()
    })
```

Thanks in Advance!